# Formatting a cell conditionally using the value of another cell, if that value is found within a column

Tags: excel

I am working on a planning tools for my workers, and I have a list of names in column "G", their initials beside their names in column F and columns "I", "K", "M", "O", "Q", "S", "U" represent all 7 days of our work schedule.

| INITIALS | NAMES | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY | MONDAY | TUESDAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| JD | John Doe | 10 | 10 |  |  |  |  |  |
| MJ | Michael Jackson |  |  |  | 10 | 10 |  |  |
| FF | Frank Fort | 10 |  |  | 10 | 10 |  |  |

I have another table on the same sheet, with the Work Orders where I make teams and manage man hours for contracts and the days of the week (columns "I", "K", "M", "O", "Q", "S", "U") are aligned with the table above it containing the manpower.

| WO # | WEDNESDAY | THURSDAY | FRIDAY | SATURDAY | SUNDAY | MONDAY | TUESDAY |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234 | JD-FF | MJ |  |  |  |  |  |

I want to add conditional formatting (Background color) to the hour columns beside the workers name, that if a value greater than 0 is entered in the "I" column beside a name, get the initials in the same row, "F" column and check in the the "J" column for the initials. This helps me quickly assign workers to respective jobs and days.

The following formula works when a single Initial set is used in the "J" column:

```
=ET(I5>0; NON(ESTERREUR(EQUIV(F5; SIERREUR(INDIRECT("J47:J80"); ""); 0))))
```

My issue is that sometimes I assign two workers in the same cell, just like the wednesday cell and the formatting stops.

I want the formatting to work in such a case.

I have tried to split the strings using the "-", and I can't seem to make it work right:

```
=ET(I5>10; OU(NON(ESTERREUR(TROUVE(F5; CHERCHE(" "&F5&"-"; " "&J47:J80&"-")))); NON(ESTERREUR(TROUVE(F5; CHERCHE("-"&F5&"-"; "-"&J47:J80&"-")))); NON(ESTERREUR(TROUVE(F5; CHERCHE("-"&F5&" "; "-"&J47:J80&" "))))))
```

Also:

```
=ET(I5>10; OU(NON(ESTERREUR(TROUVE("-"&F5&"-"; "- "&J47:J80&" -"))); NON(ESTERREUR(TROUVE(F5&"-"; J47:J80&"-"))); NON(ESTERREUR(TROUVE("-"&F5; "- "&J47:J80&" ")))))
```

Nothing works as expected.

Thanks to anyone who can help

Comment: You need to say the addresses of your tables; you only tell the column, not the rows. The result is that I apparently did not paste them at the correct rows and even the formula that works for you ended up not working for me...

Comment: If people have problems reading this question: the functions are translated in French.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. If anyone else has a similar issue, here is the formula I used and the approach.

French version:

```
=ET($I5>0; SOMMEPROD(--ESTNUM(CHERCHE(F5; SUBSTITUE($J$47:$J$80; "-"; " ")))) > 0)
```

English translation:

```
=AND($I5>0, SUMPRODUCT(--ISNUMBER(SEARCH(F5, SUBSTITUTE($J$47:$J$80, "-", " ")))) > 0)
```

1. $I5 > 0: Checks if the value in the corresponding "I" column is greater than 0.
2. SUBSTITUTE($J$47:$J$80, "-", " "): Replaces '-' with a space in the "J" column to allow for space-separated initials.
3. SEARCH(F5, ...): Searches for the worker's initials (from column F) in the modified "J" column.
4. ISNUMBER(...): Converts the search results to a boolean array where TRUE indicates a match.
5. --ISNUMBER(...): Converts TRUE to 1 and FALSE to 0.
6. SUMPRODUCT(...) > 0: Checks if there is at least one match for the worker's initials.

All I had to do is adjust the ranges. Works for me